# Error page doesn't work

Tags: servlets, http-status-code-404

I'm creating a web application using servlet 3.1. Now I need to define a custom 404 page. This is how I did:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>CafeSkeleton</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CafeSkeleton</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>ru.tenet.cafeservice</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CafeSkeleton</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404.html</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

And my little servlet method:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        byte[] bytes;
        if (request.getHeader("User-Agent").contains("mobile")) {
            bytes = viewService.getViewBytes("mobile.html");
        } else {
            bytes = viewService.getViewBytes("desktop.html");
        }
        if (bytes == null) {
            //this condition is true
            response.setStatus(404);
        } else {
            out = response.getOutputStream();
            out.write(bytes);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (out != null)
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Also I've got a custom 404.html in WebContent folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>404</title>
</head>
<body>404 Not found
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my project structure:

[image]

And pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>CafeSkeleton</groupId>
    <artifactId>CafeSkeleton</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160212</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-pool2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jmimemagic/jmimemagic -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jmimemagic</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmimemagic</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

If I run my app, I will not see this page. I can see 404 status, but no content. What is wrong?

Comment: Will you please show your project structure ?

Comment: What kind of structure are you talking about? File structure?

Comment: Your project structure.Location of error page in project structure

Comment: @Darshit, please take a look

Comment: you have to give error page location from Web-INF which loads on container...  so,in web.xml change location of error page to "\WEB-INF\404.html" instead of "\404.html"

Comment: while you load any application on tomcat server, it loads folder of web content for all view pages .. So,if you change location of you 404.html to web content directory instead of web-inf it will work. Or in web.xml change location of error page to \WEB-INF\404.html instead of \404.html . Notify me if it generates any error, but it should work ! :P